# Lumen 5.5.2 URL forceSchema not working at all

Tags: laravel-5, lumen-5.5

I am using Lumen 5.5 and using the following code chunk under app/providers/appServiceProvider.php in boot method.

\URL::forceSchema('https');

It was compatible with the earlier version of Lumen 5.2

Is there any way to sort this out without using mod_rewrite and middleware approaches.

Answer (score 8):

It appears the function has changed name from `forceSchema` to `forceScheme`.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `Lumen 5.2`.

In Laravel 5.2 or earlier version it was working fine.

> \URL::forceSchema('https');

In Laravel 5.4 or above version it changed to

> \URL::forceScheme('https');